# Dll dependency and search order

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll

I have an A.DLL which dependent on B.DLL, so does the DLL search order that applies to applications also holds for DLLs, what I meant is when A.DLL is loaded then how does it search for B.DLL? If the DLL search order does not apply to DLLs, where should I keep the B.DLL?  Should i keep it in the Current Directory where A.DLL is located or should I use form Environment paths

Note: I can't put B.DLL is System32

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The application's search rules apply, the directory that contains the EXE is always searched first.  Obviously a good place to store both A.dll and B.dll, never a DLL Hell problem that way.

Comment: Thanks Hans for the reply.
The DLL in not present in the directory that contains the EXE, infact this A.DLL is a COM Dll which implicitly links B.DLL.  can i place the B.DLL  in the same directory where A.DLL is located? i am yet to start the development of B.DLL, before i start i had these doubts so want to get clarified

Comment: You should of course mention that in your question.  A very simple trick can solve it, create an empty [app.exe.local file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The search order that applies to both exe and dll: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-desktop-applications. The first one regardless of safe mode is always "The directory from which the application loaded." In terms of dll, according to my finding via [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), it depends on if the dll is statically linked or dynamically loaded via `LoadLibrary`. For static link, this is the directory of the dll, whereas for dynamic load, this is the directory of the exe.

For example, when `C:\App.exe` loads `D:\A.dll`, which depends on `B.dll` as in your example, Windows searches `B.dll` in `D:\` if static linked, or `C:\` if loaded with `LoadLibrary`. If `B.dll` is not found there, then it proceeds to search other directories such as System32.

Down that line of search order is "The current directory". Many applications that loads external modules may have `SetDllDirectory("")` to remove current directory in the search in order to [avoid dll preloading vulnerability](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2389418/secure-loading-of-libraries-to-prevent-dll-preloading-attacks).